# Parsing XML from top down without knowing element order?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to parse XML into runnable C# code for a profile system I'm working on. Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MCBuddy>
    <ProfileName>Profile Test 2</ProfileName>
    <MCScript>
        <Log>HELLO</Log>
        <Wait>100</Wait>
        <Status>Walking forward...</Status>
        <CameraMove X="-10" Y="-10" />
        <CameraMove X="-20" Y="10" />
        <CameraMove X="6" Y="15" />
        <CameraMove X="-10" Y="-10" />
        <CameraMove X="-20" Y="10" />
        <CameraMove X="6" Y="15" />
        <CameraMove X="-10" Y="-10" />
        <PressKey>D1</PressKey>
        <CameraMove X="-20" Y="10" />
        <CameraMove X="6" Y="15" />
        <CameraMove X="-10" Y="-10" />
        <CameraMove X="-20" Y="10" />
        <CameraMove X="6" Y="15" />
        <MoveLeft>5000</MoveLeft>
        <MoveForward>1000</MoveForward>
        <EndProfile />
    </MCScript>
</MCBuddy>
```

And the C# code:

```
while (time <= mb_runningTime.Value)
                {
                    time++;
                    foreach (var mright in doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "MoveRight"))
                    {
                        PlayerActions.MoveRight(Convert.ToInt32(mright.Value));
                    }

                    foreach (var mforward in doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "MoveForward"))
                    {
                        PlayerActions.MoveForward(Convert.ToInt32(mforward.Value));
                    }

                    foreach (var mback in doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "MoveBack"))
                    {
                        PlayerActions.MoveBack(Convert.ToInt32(mback.Value));
                    }

                    foreach (var mleft in doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "MoveLeft"))
                    {
                        PlayerActions.MoveLeft(Convert.ToInt32(mleft.Value));
                    }
                    foreach (var wait in doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "Wait"))
                    {
                        Task.Delay(Convert.ToInt32(wait.Value)).Wait();
                    }
                    foreach (var log in doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "Log"))
                    {
                        Function.Log(log.Value, 1, mb_logBox);
                    }
                    foreach (var state in doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "Status"))
                    {
                        mb_statusLabel.Text = state.Value;
                    }
                    foreach (var key in doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "PressKey"))
                    {
                        PlayerActions.PressKey((Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), key.Value));
                    }
                    foreach (var msLeftClick in doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "MouseLeftClick"))
                    {
                        PlayerActions.MouseLeftClick();
                    }
                    foreach (var msRightClick in doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "MouseRightClick"))
                    {
                        PlayerActions.MouseRightClick();
                    }
                    foreach (var msLeftHold in doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "MouseLeftHold"))
                    {
                        PlayerActions.MouseLeftHold(Convert.ToInt32(msLeftHold.Value));
                    }
                    foreach (var msRightHold in doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "MouseRightHold"))
                    {
                        PlayerActions.MouseRightHold(Convert.ToInt32(msRightHold.Value));
                    }
                    foreach (var camMove in doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "CameraMove"))
                    {
                        Point move = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + Convert.ToInt32(camMove.Attribute("X").Value), Cursor.Position.Y + Convert.ToInt32(camMove.Attribute("Y").Value));
                        TimeSpan moveTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
                        LinearSmoothMove(move, moveTime);
                    }
                }
```

However, I'm running into the issue of not being able to find a way to parse it as it is, no matter what XML elements it starts with. If I keep it the way that I have it now, it will parse it in that order. I have tried multiple ways of doing this, however nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over the elements under MCScript and based on the name of the element take the appropiate action:

```
        long time=0;
        foreach (var node in xd.Document
            .Element("MCBuddy")
            .Element("MCScript")
            .Elements())
        {
            if (time > mb_runningTime.Value)
            {
                 break;
            }
            time++;
            var ele = (XElement) node;
            switch (ele.Name.ToString())
            {
                case "Status":
                    mb_statusLabel.Text = ele.Value;
                    break;
                case "CameraMove":
                    var move = new Point(
                        Cursor.Position.X + Convert.ToInt32(ele.Attribute("X").Value),
                        Cursor.Position.Y + Convert.ToInt32(ele.Attribute("Y").Value));
                    TimeSpan moveTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
                    LinearSmoothMove(move, moveTime);
                break;
                    // others go here
                default:
                    Trace.WriteLine(ele.Name);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to *Lookup*

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
var lookup = xDoc.Descendants("MCScript")
                .First()
                .Elements()
                .ToLookup(x => x.Name.LocalName);
```